# What packages did Midori install for it to run that I should uninstall to be completely rid of Midori?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, midori

I've installed Midori, tried it, and disliked it, so I've uninstalled it. Problem is, I forgot to keep track of what packages Midori installed along with itself, and since I'm trying to get rid of Midori completely, including all of the other extra packages it installed, I'm wondering if anyone happens to know what those packages are. I've installed good ole' Chromium afterwards, and are there any packages that Chromium uses that were installed by Midori as well? If not, what are the extra lib packages and whatnot that Midori installed besides the basic browser itself in order to run?

Thanks,
Icedrake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use `rdepends` for that, install it with `sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends` or look for in the Ubuntu Software Center.

After installing the program you can use it simply by opening a terminal and typing `sudo apt-rdepends <package_name>`.

It will show you all the dependencies any package that is in your `apt` lists required to install and all the dependencies of a package that you might be thinking about installing.

It shows the information in a tree diagram where all the dependencies from one package are compared against all the dependencies of the each package dependency... (and so).

ie:

> sudo apt-rdepends sqlite

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sqlite3
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0)
  Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.6.18)
libc6
  Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5)
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: tzdata
libc-bin
libgcc1
  Depends: gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
gcc-4.6-base
multiarch-support
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6)
tzdata
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: debconf-2.0
debconf
  PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4)
perl-base
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.14.20)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.11)
dpkg
  PreDepends: coreutils (>= 5.93-1)
  PreDepends: libbz2-1.0
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.11)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
  PreDepends: xz-utils
  PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
coreutils
  PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.11-1)
  PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 2.4.41-1)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.7)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
libacl1
  Depends: libattr1 (>= 2.4.41-1)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libattr1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libselinux1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
xz-utils
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7)
  Depends: liblzma2 (>= 5.0.0)
liblzma2
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
zlib1g
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
debconf-2.0
libreadline6
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11)
  Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 5.6+20070908)
  Depends: readline-common
libtinfo5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
readline-common
  Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4)
  Depends: install-info
install-info
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
libsqlite3-0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
```

---

If you just want to see what `midori` installed during the installation process (and not all the list of dependencies of `midori`) you can check your `/var/log/apt/term.log` file, it will show you all the steps `apt` has performed until now in your system, including installations and removals of packages.

Have a look at it running `cat /var/log/apt/term.log | more` in a terminal or open it with your favorite text editor.

Comment: That is actually the perfect program for me when I'm installing things in the future, and I will make sure to use it, so thank you. However, I've already uninstalled Midori and now I'm trying to get rid of the other packages that Midori installed with it that weren't removed upon the uninstallation of Midori.

Comment: A quick question about rdepends: What is the difference between Depends and PreDepends?

Comment: Simple add the ppa back, you dont need to actually install the package, after adding the ppa and `sudo apt-get update` run `sudo apt-rdepends midori` and it will show you all the necessary dependencies (direct or not) of the package `midori`.

Comment: pre-depends are dependencies which if not present on the system `dpkg` wont even think about installing the package. Normally the packages are extracted and if a dependency is not present the installation of these packages will be denied, pre-depends are so important that if exist and not present on the system `dpkg` wont even extract the files in order to check them.

Comment: It works as you told, but I'm running into a problem. It displays all of the dependencies, including ones that came default with Ubuntu but were used by Midori. I'm trying to find what packages specifically Midori installed when it was installing itself, not including what was already installed by default by Ubuntu or other programs.

Comment: Maybe I can go about this another way. Is it possible to view all packages that were installed recently? Basically a history of all the packages installed? That way I can look at the history to see when Midori was installed and what other junk came with it.

Comment: have a look at the edit, regards.

Comment: Your edit suggestion worked perfectly and I found the two items that Midori installed with itself. Surprisingly, those two items are now required by other programs, so I didn't uninstall them. o.O